# USB Device Not Recognized -warning on Unknown Device

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb

Do I have a virus or what is this bug about? What part of my computer is failing? I have been getting this warning every now and then since a month or so:

[image]

And when I click it, it shows me:

[image]

I dont own an "USB Root Hub" at all. I dont have any USB devices except mouse and keyboard connected, and 2 adapter cables that doesn't have any electronics in them, just cables. My mouse and keyboard are working fine.

Comment: Any computer with a USB port has a USB Hub.  So what USB devices do you have connected to your computer? "2 adapter cables" disconnect them, they are likely active adapters, you don't have a virus.

Comment: as @Ramhound said, you have not a virus, that should be a physical problem from the hub that you are tring to use. many devices as mp3 players or another multimedia devices that usually haves an expantion card like ssd slots or so they have a hub

Comment: The weird thing is that all my cables are working fine. So how can it sometimes not recognize it? Is my motherboard going to explode soon?

Comment: @Rookie - Before I travel deeper down this rabbit hole, have you tried my suggestion, by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound, i would have to unplug all USB cables, right? That is not possible since i use them, and the warning comes randomly, not every day or even every week maybe. Anyway i unplugged them and put them back in, problem stays.

Comment: @Rookie - What devices are connected to the two adapter cables?  What type of adapter cables.  You indicated the only USB devices you have connected to your computer was a keyboard and mouse and some sort of adapter cable(s).  I suspect the adapter cables, it makes sense for the problem to come back, if you keep plugging them in.

Comment: @Ramhound, at the moment of that warning, nothing was connected to them. The cables are adapters for mini-usb, and the other cable simply extends my computer usb slot to my desk, so i can plug in my usb sticks there etc. So basically those two cables are just extensions of the wires, no electronics in them.

Comment: The next time this happens.  Provide us the detected USB devices, listed in Device Manager, that will provide the required information to answer this question.

Comment: I had this issue once, turned out to be a bad usb cable plugged into my pc but not plugged into any device, removed the bad cable and messages stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Your device is a composite one, and it may be lacking enough power: check if it has an external power source. If it doesn't, use an intermediate USB hub with a power supply. Even if you have installed your drivers, but lack the power to "fire up" your peripheral device - such situation will occur for sure

Answer (score -3):

Step 1:
Open "Run" (<kbd>Windows Logo</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type “devmgmt.msc” and click OK.

Step 2:
Now expand Universal Serial Bus controllers.

Step 3:
Attach your device which is not recognized.

Step 4:
You will see an Unknown USB device (Port reset failed) with yellow sign in Universal Serial Bus controllers.

Unknown USB device (Port reset failed)

Step 5:
Now right click on it and click Uninstall to remove them.

Step 6:
Now restart your PC and re-install the USB drivers again. That’s it.

Step 7:
If not working, then Uninstall all devices under Universal Serial Bus controllers one by one and re-install.

<sup>Source: "[Solved: USB Device Not Recognized In Windows](https://www.wiknix.com/usb-device-not-recognized)", Wiknix</sup>

Comment: One method assumes the user has a laptop.  The other I might consider helpful, if I didn't have to vist a website, full of hostile ads.

Comment: Just use Adblock Plus

Comment: I do use it, thats also how, I know the website was infected with ads.  I have an equally helpful comment to post also, submit helpful answers, instead of link only answers that point to websites infested with ads.  Once the answer has been formatted I will consider removing my downvote.

Comment: Use Adblock Plus plugin in your firefox browser. It will be more helpful. I am using this, so I didn't able to see any ads. Therefore I posted the link.

Comment: I already use Firefox.  Does not change the fact, your original revision, was a link only answer to a ad infested website.